# JPA-QL get max(count(foreign_key))

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I need to generate a named query.

I have to tables with an 1:n relationship. Now I would like to join this to tables and count the entries grouped by the foreign_key. This works fine so far but now I want to get only the maximum value of the query before. I tried a lot but couldn't find out how it would work. Any advise?

```
select count(l) from Table1 ll join ll.table1 l group by l
```

So far everything work but I can't get the max value of this statement.

greetings stefan

Comment: why should this statement return only one row. I have already tested it and I get exactly two rows. One row with value 3 and one row with value 1. What I want now is to get the maximum value of these two rows -> in this particular case 3.

Comment: Yup! I accidentally forgot to consider the `GROUP BY` clause. Since you need to obtain a maximum value of the result of count of each group, you will need a sub-query in the `FROM` clause in this case. Example : `SELECT MAX(t1.cnt) AS max FROM (SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM table t GROUP BY t.id) t1`. Since ORM frameworks do not support sub-queries in the `FROM` clause (only newer versions of EclipseLink support sub-queries in the `FROM` clause only with JPQL - not criteria), you will have to execute a native SQL statement directly on the database.

Comment: Thanks anyway. You pointed me in the right direction and found out that I can access the size directly. `select l from Table1 where l.table2.size = (select max(t.table2.size) from Table2 join tt.table1 t) ` and it works like a charm.